# displaying nested beans in a primefaces, JSF webapp

Tags: java, spring, jsf, primefaces

In my JSF page I have the following:

```
<h:outputText value="#{entity[column.key]}" />
```

my enity bean (simple version):

```
public class Entity implements Serializable {
private int id;
private Entity entity;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Entity getEntity() {
    return this.entity;
}
public void setEntity(Entity entity) {
    this.entity = entity;
}
}
```

when my [column.key] variable is holding as value 'id', the id attribute of the Entity is displayed.
When my [column.key] variable is holding as value 'entity.id', I get an error:

> /WEB-INF/flows/parametersPage/parametersPage.xhtml @51,66 value="#{entity[column.key]}": Property 'entity.id' not found on type eu.acsone.agc.db.entity.Entity

When I debug, I see that the entity is set in the bean, so it is not null.

I hope you guys can help, thanks!

I'm using:
* Mojarra 2.1.7
* Primefaces 3.3.1

Answer (score 2):

its cause you don't have a property (which is actually an illegal in java - no dot separator is allowed )

```
private int entity.id; //its not even legal
```

in your bean

when you try to access to your bean like this `value="#{entity[variableThatHoldSomeString]}":`

JSF will look for a property `SomeString` in your bean... that's why you are getting this error
try something like this

```
value="#{entity.entity[column.key]}":
```

where `[column.key]` variable will hold a value 'id',

(b.t.w the nested property of the same type look weird to me)

Comment: I don't think he wants to resolve an integer called "entity.id", but wants to reach the "id" field of the field "entity". He's probably doing something weird, but technically an EL function using eg bean utils could resolve it.